# I want generate an alert dialog if login fail in PHP,JS but finding issue

Tags: javascript, php, http-headers, alert

```
 if($row['psw']===$passwordphp)
          {

             echo '<script language="javascript">';
             echo 'alert("LOGIN SUCCESSFULL")';
             echo '</script>';
             header("Location: registration.php");
          }
       else{

             echo '<script language="javascript">';
             echo 'alert("CHECK EMAIL OR PASSWORD")';
             echo '</script>';
             header("Location: login.php");
             }
```

Here is the code. If I don't add header then JavaScript runs but when I add header Javascript stop running only executes the header function. Why is so? How can make both of them work properly?

Comment: you'd be better off using ajax for this. At the moment you are already outputting something to the browser, then calling php `header()`

Comment: This `$row['psw']===$passwordphp` makes me think you're storing the passwords in plain text? That's a _massive_ security issue. You should use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to create a hash of the password, which is what you store. Then use [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to verify the password the user enters against the stored hash.

Comment: Yes is there any better way? Please suggest it would be really helpful @MagnusEriksson

Comment: My comment contains links to both password_hash() and password_verify() in the manual. Read those pages and check the examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the other answer, you can't send a header redirect and also send HTML.

Instead of the header redirect, you can use a Javascript redirect after the alert.

```
if($row['psw']===$passwordphp) {
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("LOGIN SUCCESSFULL");';
    echo 'window.location = "registration.php";';
    echo '</script>';
} else {
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("CHECK EMAIL OR PASSWORD");';
    echo 'window.location = "login.php"';
    echo '</script>';
}
```

Comment: Side note: if you do this, your users will be screwed if they've disabled JS. :P Might want to print out a link to the new location too, in a noscript tag.

Comment: it's not working its showing blank page..js is enabled in my browser

Comment: Need semicolons after `alert()`, I've added them.

Comment: Did you check for errors in the Javascript console? That would have pointed out the problem.

Answer (score 3):

A `Location` header tells the browser to drop everything and do something else. You can't do a `Location` redirect *and* output HTML.

That said, this code *should* throw a ["Headers already sent" error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php), as you can't do a `header` call after echoing anything to the browser.

Comment: Thanks for the typo fix, @ScottMarcus!

Comment: so I cant use alert message and header simultaneously right?

Comment: @StackQueue Correct. You have a number of options. The most popular tends to be saving the status/error in a session value and displaying that on the destination page you're redirecting to. Often called "flashing" to the session.

Comment: Just to mention, if output buffering is on and the buffer hasn't been filled yet, you can output headers even after the text output starts.

Comment: @cHao Good point, that may explain why this isn't parse erroring.